# Make specific case execute last in switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I need to make a `case` execute at the last. Any ideas?

```
 $.each(dataNames, function (varName, itemVal) {
    switch (varName)
    {
       case "afshin": 
           alert('afshin');
           break;
       case "saeed": 
           alert('saeed');
           break;
       case "larry": 
           alert('larry');
           break;
       case "abc": 
           alert('abc');
           break;
       default: 
           alert('Default case');
           break;
    }
});
```

from the code above i need the case `'abc'` to get executed at the last of all cases as i'm manipulating some code which has to execute from the other cases.

FYI, `dataNames` is a `JSON` object

Comment: add a new property to the dataNames object with any name thats not in your switch cases... `dataNames.whatever = '';`

Comment: If you need "abc" to run last than you probably need to do something different than loop over the keys of the object since it has no order.

Comment: Maybe use a flag to check if "abc" was found. Then do whatever you need to do outside the `each` ?

Comment: Done it outside each. Thanks @MaazSyedAdeeb